# Generate dynamic meta-tags based on URL

Tags: php, dynamic, meta-tags

I'm trying to ASSIGN dynamically exclusive meta-tags for each page:

i.e:
**url.com/index.php?action=signup**

Header - Signup Title

Keywords - Signup Meta Keywords

Description - Signup Description

**url.com/index.php?action=about**

Header - About Title

Keywords - About Meta Keywords

Description - About Description

You got the point.

I'm using arrays...but didn't figured yet HOW TO ASSIGN each array to each page.

**CONF.PHP**

```
<?php
$metas = array( 
'index.php' => array( 
'header' => 'Home Title', 
'keywords' => 'Home Meta Keywords', 
'description' => 'Home Meta Description' 
), 
'signup' => array( 
'header' => 'Signup Title', 
'keywords' => 'Signup Meta Keywords', 
'description' => 'Signup Meta Description' 
), 
'about' => array( 
'header' => 'About Title', 
'keywords' => 'About Meta Keywords', 
'description' => 'About Meta Description' 
) 
);
?>
```

**INDEX.PHP**

```
<TITLE><?php echo $metas['title']; ?></TITLE>
<meta name="description" content="<?php echo $metas['description']; ?>" >
<meta name="keywords" content="<?php echo $metas['keywords']; ?>" >
```

How to ASSIGN those values to each page???

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are on the right track :-)

Do it in following way:

```
<TITLE><?php echo $metas['index.php']['title']; ?></TITLE>
```

Script name you can get it from the $_SERVER super global array/variable.

Also from your config.php file remove last 3 lines, you don't need them.

Good luck, with PHP make sure you get good knowledge about playing with array. That's key.

EDIT:

```
$page = 'index.php';
if ( isset( $_GET['action'] ) && $_GET['action'] != "" )
{
    $page = $_GET['action'];
}

<TITLE><?php echo $metas[$page]['title']; ?></TITLE>
```

EDIT: (on 27th May 2012)

I think this is pretty much everything:

Your code in config.php

```
<?php

$meta['INDEX']['title'] = "Home page";
$meta['INDEX']['keywords'] = "kwd1, kwd2, kwd3";
$meta['INDEX']['description'] = "Home description";

$meta['SIGNUP']['title'] = "Sign up..!";
$meta['SIGNUP']['keywords'] = "kwd1, kwd2, kwd3";
$meta['SIGNUP']['description'] = "Sign up description";

$meta['ABOUT']['title'] = "About Company";
$meta['ABOUT']['keywords'] = "kwd1, kwd2, kwd3";
$meta['ABOUT']['description'] = "About company description";
```

Your code in any of your application page/screen (.php files):

```
<?php

include "config.php";

// Choice 1: if you want to specify page hardcoded at each page then you can say $page = 'ABOUT' for about-us page and $page = 'INDEX' for home page etc.
$page = 'ABOUT';
if( strtoupper($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $page) !== false )
{
    $title = $meta[$page]['title'];
    $keywords = $meta[$page]['keywords'];
    $description = $meta[$page]['description'];
}
// Now you have your meta - use it the way you want
echo $title;

// Choice 2: If you want to make it little more dynamic
// Here you don't need to define any hardcoded variable at page level as everything will be considered from the URL being requested
$page_index = array_keys($meta);

foreach($page_index as $page)
{

    if ( strpos( strtoupper($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']), $page ) !== false)
    {
        $title = $meta[$page]['title'];
        $keywords = $meta[$page]['keywords'];
        $description = $meta[$page]['description'];
        break;
    }
}
// Now you have your meta - use it the way you want
echo $title;

?>
```

Comment: But, how can I put index.php array at index.php if all pages are loaded inside it? SIGNUP - index.php?action=signup / ABOUT - index.php?action=about...etc

Comment: I used switch method to assign values.
But now I have problems for assigning variables get from a MySQL select...how can I do that?

Ex:
url.com/news/$id/$title
 - 
How to assign meta tags in such case?

Comment: In that case you have to search for specific word on your full URL using strpos($haystack, $findme) method. If you find news you should use those meta tags and so on. So you can do it 2 way 1) use action or 2) if action is blank look for your keyword using strpos and get the right meta tag from the config.

Comment: Can you be more specific please?

Comment: @Darkeden I have added an example to support my comment. Please check.

Comment: @Darkeden did that made more sense, after I updated answer with updated code/example?